# Convert string time like (0740) into 12 hours (AM,PM) time format like (07:40 AM)

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i convert string time into **12 hours (AM,PM)** time format?
**Like** if input string will like "2320" than i want answer like "11:20 PM".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string s = DateTime.ParseExact("2320","HHmm",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
       .ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: (oops, missed the culture-info; added)

Comment: shouldn't this use a culture info thats set to use 24h system instead of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture?

Comment: @Petoj: I believe the capital Hs already indicate a 24h system (otherwise the string would be "hhmm").

Comment: @Petoj - in this case, the culture doesn't make any difference; Invariant would be fine...

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure its been mentioned many times, but here is the reference for the to string parameters for Datetime [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

In Marc's answer, there is a leading zero in the hours if it is a single digit hour.

```
string s = DateTime.ParseExact("2320", "HHmm").ToString("h:mm tt");
```

The above would provide the format we're used to seeing from most digital clocks these days.